# How to access my local system Postgres from Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker

When I use Docker on my own machine, I want to access my system's Postgres. This is prior to deploying my images to AWS, where I want to use RDS.

I have followed the steps on [Docker's Quickstart: Docker Compose and Rails page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) with the exception that, because I was working with an existing application, I didn't create the initial minimal Gemfile that just loads Rails.

Outside of the Docker container, Postgres is installed and working correctly:

```
$ which postgres
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/postgres
$ which pg_restore
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_restore
$ which pg_dump
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_dump
```

The app has been working fine without Docker for years. To test the app outside of the Docker container once more, I have comment out one line of Docker's recommended `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  # host: db

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

When I do that, I can run `rake db:test:clone` (for example) outside of the container no worries:

But when I uncomment that line and connect to a TTY in the container, I'm in all sorts of pain:

```
/myapp# rake db:test:clone                                          
pg_dump -s -x -O -f /myapp/db/structure.sql postgres
Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `pg_dump` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.
/myapp# which postgres
/myapp# which pg_restore
/myapp# which pg_dump
/myapp#
```

What can I do?

The Dockerfile, based on Docker's instructions with a few extra binaries required by my existing app, is:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1-slim

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing build-essential
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing git
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing xvfb
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing qt5-default
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing libqt5webkit5-dev
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing gstreamer1.0-tools
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing gstreamer1.0-x
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing nodejs
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing libpq-dev

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

ADD . /myapp
```

Related: I can see `redis-cli` outside the container but not inside it. This will be an issue too once I solve the Postgres situation.

**Update**

When I go in like this...

```
docker-compose run web rake db:create
docker-compose run web rake db:test:clone
```

...it seems I can access Postgres, but not `pg_dump` and other utilities required for `rake db:test:clone`, `rake db:test:load` or similar.

**Update II**

I added the following to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing postgresql-client
```

Now, instead of giving me a "can't be found" error, it says:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.5.4; pg_dump version: 9.4.9
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

This is an issue you can find discussed elsewhere, but not in the context of Docker, which is crucial here.

Would it help if I downgraded my Mac's Postgres to the version fetched by `apt-get`? Upgrading the version installed by `apt-get` appears not to be an option:

```
Step 15 : RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing postgresql-client-9.5
 ---> Running in 614b88701710
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-9.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-client-9.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't "yer doin it wrong", this is tricky.  I ran through the docker intro you linked and I couldn't get it to work.

Here's what I did for our app.  I built our app off of a base image named after the app.  The base image is named after the app.  So using your example it'd be called `myapp_base`.  I don't see your docker-compose.yml file here so I'll make some assumptions.

`web:
  image: your_company/myapp_base
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  # ports:
  #  - "3002:3002"
  # env_file:
  #  - .myapp.env`

Port and env_file are not needed but they might come in handy later.  `Myapp_base` is built with a weird workflow that pulls in deps but basically throws in `postgres-client` if the app is declared to need postgres.  It's in chef but it's basically `myapp runlist needs postgresql`.  We're actually moving away from this and trying to put the setup stuff in scripts and the Dockerfile itself.

So ... basically just add the `apt-get install postgres-client` to your Dockerfile, tag it as `myapp_base` and use that in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  Then run the `docker-compose run web rake db` stuff and psql will be found.

Comment: Thanks. This looks in principle like it should work. (But then, so did the Docker docs.) But I ended up deploying to ElasticBeanstalk without Docker in the end.